# Как пакет данных доходит от моста сетей до получателя?

Tags: сеть, ip

Предположим есть 2 сети, которые одним мостом соединяются в одну. Один узел хочет послать данные на другой узел в другой сети. Как вообще он понимает, что данные нужно посылать именно на шлюз и как потом эти данные с моста попадают на конечный узел?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]